# Behavior subject in Rxjs and Angular, how to get an array out of the whole json file

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have an Api endpoint that points to the sample data.

The whole json file format is like this, I want to make the Objects[] as behavior subject, and maybe the ingore shapes[] as well. I tried to follow some code examples, since the Objects[] is just part of the whole json file, I don't know the syntax of accessing just the objects array instead of the whole file to be the behavior subject.

object.ts

```
export interface Objects {
      name: String;
      height: Number;
      length: Number;
      width: Number;
      mass: Number;
      
}

export interface WholeJson {
      objects: Array<Objects>,
      ignoreShapes: Array<String>,
      liquidDensity: Number
}
```

rest.service.ts

```
private _objectsSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<Objects[]>([]);
  

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

  getObjectsData(): Observable<Objects[]> {
    return this._objectsSource$.asObservable();
        
  }

  refreshObjectsData(): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.ApiEndpoint).pipe
    (map(({objects}: {objects: any}) => objects));
  }
```

component.ts

```
objects: Objects[] = [];
density: Number = 0;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private readonly restService: RestService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.getObjects();
    this.restService.getObjectsData().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )    
  }
```

It ends up just return an empty array in the console. Please give me a hint of what to do, I struggle to find codes example with similar case in Angular 15!!!

Comment: somewhere you should be calling `next()` onto your subject.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a DataSource class to extract your data logic.

```
export class ObjectDataSource implements DataSource<Objects> {
  private _objectsSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<Objects[]>([]);

  public loading: boolean = true;
  constructor(private service : Service) {}
  connect(): Observable<Objects[]> {
    return this._objectsSource$.asObservable();
  }
  disconnect(): void {
    this._objectsSource$.complete();
  }

  getObjects(id: number) {
    this.service
      .refreshObjectsData()
      .subscribe({
        next: object => {
          this._objectsSource$.next(object);
          this.loading = false;
        },
        error: (err: Error) => {
           //handle errors
        },
      });
  }
```

When you need the data in your class you can just call it this way:

```
ngOnInit():void {
this.dataSource = new ObjectDataSource(this.service);
this.dataSource.connect().subscribe(data => {//Do something with your data});
}
```

Also with this loading boolean you are able to display some kind of loading indicator.